# Por qué mis teclas de funciones (F1..F12) no funcionan en mi evento keypress?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día programadores tengo un inconveniente necesito ejecutar eventos keypress (jquery) he intentado con códigos simples bajados de internet y funciona con teclas simples (a,b,1,2, etc) pero al momento de usar las teclas F1 o hasta F12 no funciona.

este es el código que estoy probando:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#buscar").keypress(function(e) {
                alert("Pulsaste la tecla dentro del campo de texto con código: "+e.which);
                  });         
            });
    </script>
    <title>nada</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="buscar" />
</body>
</html>
```

Que puedo hacer? necesito usar esas teclar realmente, estoy usando de exploradores (firefox, chrome y safari) sistema operativo Mac os HS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las teclas de función, tradicionalmente solo producen eventos [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)/[`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event), pero no `keypress`, por lo que podrías basarte en ellos para la funcionalidad que buscas implementar.

Prueba este ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#buscar").keydown(function(e) {
       let sTeclas = "";
       sTeclas += e.shiftKey?"[shift] ":"";
       sTeclas += e.ctrlKey?"[ctrl] ":"";
       sTeclas += e.altKey?"[alt] ":"";
       console.log("key: " + sTeclas + e.key);
       if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == "F1" && !e.shiftKey && !e.altKey) {
         alert("felicitaciones, ha presionado ctrl + F1");
       }
   });         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="buscar" />
```

En la consola voy dejando mensajes cada vez que se dispara el evento, que soporta *combinaciones de teclas*, como <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Debes tomar en cuenta que, mientras una tecla permanezca presionada, el evento `keydown` se dispara periódicamente, a menos que se presione otra (por ejemplo para las combinaciones de teclas). Mi sugerencia es experimentar con él para ver como funciona.

He dejado, en el ejemplo, que se muestre una alerta cuando se presiona <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: osea que no puedo hacer que me muestre un alert por ejemplo o realizar una acción con esto?

Comment: claro que podrías, pero te recomiendo hacer pruebas primero, porque este evento funciona diferente que el `keypress`, por ejemplo, si una tecla permanece presionada, el evento `keydown` se dispara muchas veces, de manera repetitiva, según puedes ver en mi ejemplo. Por lo mismo, es que he sustituido tu `alert` por un mensaje en la consola.

Comment: pero en este caso se podría usar keyup que creo que no pasará lo mismo

Comment: Claro, mi ejemplo está hecho con `keydown`, pero tu usa lo que más te convenga. Hice una edición de la respuesta para mejorar un poco la explicación y ampliar el ejemplo. Espero con eso te quede más claro.

Comment: Si te lo agradezco bastante, es exactamente lo que andaba buscando

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, me llama la atención que has hecho un buen número de preguntas y en ninguna has marcado una respuesta como aceptada, @MauEspaña, ¿si sabes como funciona el sitio?. Te invito a leer [que puedes hacer cuando recibes respuestas a tus preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y a re-visitar las que creas que valga la pena votar y aceptar. Un saludo.